# android button with round color, background image, and selector

Tags: android, button

Now the button is round corner and filled with solid green when not pressed, and become solid blue with round corner when pressed. Codings are as follows:

I would like to ask how could the following be modified if I want

1. set background images for pressed and not pressed for the button instead of solid blue and green
2. how could I add paddings to the button because now all the buttons are sticking to each other.. I have declared padding in xml but not successful

### In xml:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_span="4"
        android:background="@drawable/story_btn"
        android:onClick="buttonC_click"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="abc"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
```

### In story_btn.xml

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >         
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/red" />
        <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
        <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
            android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
        <corners android:radius="15dp" /> 
    </shape>    
</item>

<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/black" />
        <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="2dp" 
            android:right="5dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
        <corners android:radius="15dp" /> 
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your story_btn.xml, instead of specifying a shape for each item, specify a drawable like android:drawable="@drawable/activity_active".
2. Use Layout_margin to specify the margin between the buttons.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! #2 works! regarding #1, if the original pic is rectangle with angle, how could I make it as round corners (if i want to fine tune the radius then need to rebuild the pic everytime?)

Comment: Sorry, I can not think of an easier way to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can place rounded color image itself, you no need to create round color. Then you can apply style for `state:pressed` and `state:selected` place the image you want, defaultly you have another image  in item tag